# TestNG with dataProvider skips tests if one has been failed

Tags: testng

Here is my suite.xml with test classes

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="Mobile">
        <listeners>
            <listener class-name="TestNGSuiteListener"/>
            <listener class-name="TestNGListener"/>
            <listener class-name="PriorityInterceptor"/>
        </listeners>
        <test name="testMobile" preserve-order="true">
            <classes>
                <class name="mobile.BookingTest"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

Here is a test class

```
    @DataProvider(name = "differentCards")
public static Object[][] differentCards() {
    return new Object[][]{
            {visa, cardCvv},
            {visaDebit, cardCvv}
    };
}

 @Test(groups = "mobileTests", dataProvider = "differentCards")
    public void booking_test(String cardNumber, String cardCvv) {
            //steps of test
 }
```

I don't understand, why TestNG skips runs of test with remaining data parameters, if test has been failed with first parameters ?

How to fix such behaviour, to make TestNG execute test with all the data parameters ?

Comment: I just tried your source code and i can run all your tests. I tried purposely failing one of the test and it run the other test data parameter too. Can you paste complete stacktrace and which version of testng are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
configfailurepolicy="continue"
```

This setting has helped me in suite.xml